# Difference between request.getSession().getId() and request.getSession(false)?

Tags: java, javascript

What do these calls actually mean in terms of session?

```
System.out.println("print1: "+request.getSession().getId());
System.out.println("print2: "+request.getSession(false));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
print1: D94146A347D95563186EB7525726336B
print2: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@d52411
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`HttpSession session = request.getSession();` Inside the service method we ask for the session and every thing gets automatically, like the creation of the HttpSession object. There is no need to generate the unique session id. There is  no need to make a new Cookie object. Everything happens automatically behind the scenes.

As soon as call the method `getSession()` of the request object a new object of the session gets created by the container and a unique session id generated to maintain the session. This session id is transmitted back to the response object so that whenever the client makes any request then it should also attach the session id with the requsest object so that the container can identify the session.

`request.getSession(false)` : This method will check whether Session already existed for the request or not. If it existed then it will return the already existed Session. If Session is not already existed for this request then this method will return NULL, that means this method says that the request does not have a Session previously.

Comment: but why do their value change if i use anchor tag to redirect to another page

Comment: when you redirect then you lost session so on every script You must use session_start() at the beginning of EVERY script

Comment: yes i am not able to retrieve value of session and the above two value change when i redirect to another page

Comment: because you lost session after redirect so please use session_start() at the beginning of EVERY script

Comment: me using javascript to redirect the page with the help of window.navigate("del.jsp?+name="+delno); i am not able to receieve value od delno on next page ,i used req.getParameter bt no hope

Comment: use this request.getParameter("name") on another page

Comment: thankx manish  window.navigate("del.jsp?name="+delno); is correct i had used + wrongly placed :)

Answer (score 17):

*In short*-

`request.getSession().getId()` - returns  a string containing the unique identifier assigned to this session. The identifier is assigned by the servlet container and is implementation dependent.

`request.getSession(false)` - return session object or null if there's no current session.

Answer (score 5):

First line will return the "session id" on server.
The second line will return session object. So what will be printed on system.out would be `request.getSession(false).toString();`

The default implementation of `toString` returns the "object id". `Object id` in terms of session is not the same as `session id`. Session could be serialized and replicated across the cluster so on each node of the cluster on each JVM it may have it's own object id (but should have same session id).

Calling get session with boolean is explained here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean)

Answer (score 4):

```
    request.getSession()
```

This method will check for the existing session;if exist its return otherwise create a new session for the request.

```
    request.getSession().getId();
```

This will return the unique identifier for that session.

```
    request.getSession(false);
```

This method takes the boolean value.This method check whether there is an existing session present for that user(request);if exist it return that session otherwise it return null i.e it won't create new session.

Just to add more information for session.

```
    request.getSession(true);
```

This method checks for the existing current session for that user(request) and if the session exist it will return that session or otherwise it create new session for that user.

```
    request.getSession() works like request.getSession(true)
```

Reference : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29

Comment: what will be returned if there's no session and we do this: `request.getSession(true).getId();`

Answer (score 2):

```
request.getSession().getId()
```

Returs the id of the session.

`Request.getsession(false)` returns the already existing session object. It wont return anything i.e. Will return null , if session does not exist. Whereas with `true` parameter it will create a new session object and return it if no session exists

Answer (score 1):

```
request.getSession().getId();
```

Will return unique string id assigned to already started session. Generation of id is vendor specific like apache, jboss etc.

```
request.getSession(false);
```

It will return session object associated to particular request if session object is associated it will be returned or it will return null if its is not started by server.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getSession().getId();
```

this will return the id of the an existing session.

```
Request.getsession(false)
```

it will return the session if it exists, or it will return null otherwise.

and Request.getsession(false) means : give me the session if it exists, otherwise do not create a new instance (and thus return null).

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getSession().getId();
```

returns the unique identifier assigned to this session. And It has return type of String.

```
request.getSession(false)
```

returns the HttpSession object if it already exists else return null.