# Difference between request.getSession() and request.getSession(true)

Tags: java, jsp, http, session, servlets

I understand the difference between `request.getSession(true)` and `request.getSession(false)`. But `request.getSession()` & `request.getSession(true)` look very similar!

Both "return the current session associated with this request", but differ in:

### `request.getSession()`:

> "or if the request does not have a session, **creates one**"

### `request.getSession(true)`:

> "if there is no current session, **returns a new session**"

I don't understand the difference between them, is it that (if none exists) they create a new session but the first one doesn't **return** it but the second one does?

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

**Edit:**

Someone tagged/marked my question as duplicate even though it isn't. I will explain why.

I have explicitly asked for the difference between `request.getSession()` & `request.getSession(true)` and NOT between `request.getSession(true)` & `request.getSession(false)`! I have stated , again explicitly, that I already understand the difference b/w `..(true)` & `..(false)`.

The question [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969672/difference-between-request-getsession-getid-and-request-getsessionfalse) as a possible duplicated of of asks about the difference b/w `..(true)` & `..(false)` and not `..(true)` & `..()`

Comment: All 3 answers are correct, similar and useful, however @Jan was the first to answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between request.getSession().getId() and request.getSession(false)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969672/difference-between-request-getsession-getid-and-request-getsessionfalse)

Comment: @KrutikJayswal Did you even READ my question before flagging it? I EXPLICITLY stated that I am NOT asking about difference between ..Session(true) & ..Session(false)! or (implicitly) b/w ..Session() & ..Session(false)! I asked about difference between ..Session() & ..Session(true)! for which I received perfectly reasonable answers! Upon which I marked my question "[SOLVED]"!!!

Comment: @Sotiros Why did you edit my question?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`request.getSession()` is just a convenience method. It does exactly the same as `request.getSession(true)`.

Answer (score 81):

`request.getSession()` will return a current session. if current session does not exist, then **it will create a new one**.

`request.getSession(true)` will return current session. If current session does not exist, then **it will create a new session**.

So basically there is not difference between both method.

`request.getSession(false)` will return current session if current session  exists. If not, **it will *not* create a new session**.

Comment: This will create a new session if the current session is null and we don't want that. If current session is null, log him out instantly.

Comment: Above answer is easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Method with boolean argument :

```
  request.getSession(true);
```

returns new session, if the session is not associated with the request

```
  request.getSession(false);
```

returns null, if the session is not associated with the request.

Method without boolean argument :

```
  request.getSession();
```

returns new session, if the session is not associated with the request and returns the existing session, if the session is associated with the request.It won't return null.

Answer (score 4):

They both return the same thing, as noted in the documentation you linked; an
 HttpSession object.

You can also look at a concrete implementation (e.g. [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)) and see what it's actually doing: [Request.java](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java) class. In this case, basically they both call:

```
Session session = doGetSession(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

A major practical difference is its use:

in `security scenario` where we always needed a new session, we should use `request.getSession(true)`.

```
request.getSession(false): will return null if no session found.
```

Answer (score 1):

`request.getSession(true)` and `request.getSession()` both do the same thing, but if we use 
`request.getSession(false)` it will return `null` if session object not created yet.

Answer (score 0):

request.getSession() or request.getSession(true)  both will return a current session only . if current session will not exist then it will create a new session.