# use one session attribute for different servlets

Tags: java, session, servlets

I've made a login environment for a user, i've retrieved username and password from database for login.And set user name as a string in a session.now i want to use same user name for another servlet.But i can't use the same string in two servlet.How can i use the same session attribute for another servlet.Below is my code.
`loginservlet`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/LoginServlet"})
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

String userid, pwd;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    userid = request.getParameter("uname");
    pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    try {
        dbconnector dbc = new dbconnector();
        connection = dbc.Open();
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from member where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'");

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
            //out.println("welcome " + userid);
            //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
            response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
        } else {

            request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid user or password");
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

`profile servlet` here i want to use the session value userid

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/usesesvaluegetdbdata"})
public class usesesvaluegetdbdata extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    String userid;

    try {
        dbconnector dbc = new dbconnector();
        connection = dbc.Open();
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select eid,ename from member where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'");



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: how about `session.getAttribute("userid")` ?

Comment: Hint: PreparedStatement can't prevent SQL injection attacks when you stubbornly string-concatenate the query parameters straight in the SQL string instead of using the special setXxx() methods of PreparedStatement class.

Comment: As to your concrete problem, *"But i can't use the same string in two servlet"*, can you please elaborate "can't" in detail? There is namely no technical limitation, so this must be an user/developer limitation, but you have nowhere elaborated that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first `servlet` you are storing value(s) in `session` like.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
```

In the same you need to retrieve those values from `session` in second `servlet` like

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String userid=(String)session.getAttribute("userid");//cast to String, default its Object
```

Now use this `userid` variable in the second `servlet`.

[HttpSession#getAttribute()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#method_summary)

[preparestatement](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/) follow like this to avoid sql injection

[session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980616/difference-between-request-getsession-request-getsessiontrue)

Answer (score 0):

first store the value in session like this

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
```

Access the session value like this

```
  HttpSession session=request.getSession();
  String username = session.getAttribute("userid").toString() ;
```

Answer (score -1):

In the 'profile' servlet you can lookup HttpSession using following method.

HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession( false );

'false' will make sure you don't create new session in case profile servlet is called before login servlet.

Once you get the session you can read the value of attribute stored earlier.

Answer (score -1):

What do u meant by i can't use ?

if u want to use stored value in other servlet do this
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String user= session.getAttribute("userid");

if u want to use same key("userid") to set new value into it
you cannot do that because session scope is common everywhere even if you create new session object you are using same session in background so you should choose new string.

Answer (score -1):

try this ....

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/LoginServlet"})
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    String userid, pwd;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;

        userid = request.getParameter("uname");
        pwd = request.getParameter("pass");

    try {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);//true if first session else use false
        if (SessionManager.checkUserSession(session)) {
            dbconnector dbc = new dbconnector();
            connection = dbc.Open();
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from member where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'");

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {

                session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
                //out.println("welcome " + userid);
                //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
                response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
            } else {

                request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid user or password");
                RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
                rd.include(request, response);

            }
        }
        request.setAttribute("statuscode", "HTTP_STATUS_INVALID_SESSION");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

code for sessionmanager

```
public class SessionManager {

    public static boolean checkUserSession(HttpSession loginSession) {
        if ((loginSession == null) || (loginSession.toString().isEmpty())) {
            return false;
        } else if (loginSession.isNew()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

for changing the user name or accessing it use

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String userid=(String)session.getAttribute("userid");
```