# Not able to set session factory through servlet.xml using Spring MVC and Hibernate 5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, dao

I want to set session factory in DAO class but after execution I got this issue. In my class i am setting sessionFactory variable through @Autowired annotation but it is not able to set the session Factory.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field sessionFactory in com.springboot.webcrud.dao.ClienteDao required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**WHEN I REMOVE THE @Autowired ANNOTATION THEN THE SESSION FACTORY IS ALWAYS NULL WHEN I TRY TO GET THE CURRENT SESSION**

This is my project structure: [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3ajO.png)

**pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>webcrud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mvc</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>WEB CRUD</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Dependencias de desarrollo -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--Dependencias base de datos -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties file**

**I'm not able to serve the jsp files without declaring this in the properties file. I fear the hibernate configuration is not properly set since the servlet.xml file seems not to be enough. I don't get why the servlet.xml file is not enough**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
```

**web.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>MVC APP</display-name>

    <absolute-ordering />

    <!-- Configuracion del dispatcher servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Ubicacion URL del servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

**servlet.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Paquete de escaneo de componentes -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springboot.webcrud"/>

    <!-- Conversión formateo y validación-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Configuración Spring MVC directorio view  -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Origen BBDD y connection pool -->
    <bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tienda?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
        <property name="user" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="BaseDeDatos2022"/>

        <!-- Propiedades connection pool para C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000"/>
    </bean>

    <!--  Configuración Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springboot.webcrud.entity"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="ClienteDao" name="ClienteDao" class="com.springboot.webcrud.dao.ClienteDao">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" name="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!--  Configuración Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="txManager" name="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Habilitar configuración de transacciones basadas en anotaciones -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

</beans>
```

**Entity class**

```
package com.springboot.webcrud.entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "clientes")
public class Cliente {

    public Cliente() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    String id;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    String nombre;

    @Column(name = "apellido")
    String apellido;

    @Column(name = "email")
    String email;
}
```

**DAO Class**

**When I remove the @Autowired annotation then the sessionFactory is always null when I try to get the current session**

```
package com.springboot.webcrud.dao;

import com.springboot.webcrud.entity.Cliente;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class ClienteDao implements IClienteDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Cliente> listarClientes() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            System.out.println("SESION NULA");
            return null;
        }
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println("SESION OK");
        Query<Cliente> query = session.createQuery("from Cliente", Cliente.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
package com.springboot.webcrud.controller;

import com.springboot.webcrud.dao.IClienteDao;
import com.springboot.webcrud.entity.Cliente;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/tienda")
public class TiendaController {

    @Autowired
    IClienteDao servicioCliente;

    @RequestMapping("/clientes")
    public String listarClientes(Model model) {
        System.out.println("Página de clientes");

        List<Cliente> clientes = servicioCliente.listarClientes();
        model.addAttribute("clientes", clientes);
        for (Cliente cliente : clientes
        ) {
            System.out.println(cliente.toString());
        }

        return "listaClientes";
    }
}
```

Please I appreciate your help I've been stuck here for several days.

Comment: can you please add complete stack trace?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the way the session is established. Ex.:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969672/difference-between-request-getsession-getid-and-request-getsessionfalse/13969788